# How to start a graphical session in Backtrack Linux

Tags: backtrack

I just started looking at backtrack(i'm on a linux testing streak) and when I start it up I don't see a desktop. Help?

Comment: Using latest version

Comment: ^How about adding this comment to your original question?

Comment: If you are interested in backtrack, I suggest you take a look at kali linux. Its from the same creators. http://www.kali.org

Answer (score 4):

Type `startx` and the desktop should apear

Comment: I think you mean `startx`

Comment: Ah yes, I did mean that.